# convert timestamp information to session information Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

| user | timestamp | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:53:06 | 0 |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:54:06 | 1 |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:56:36 | 2.5 |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:57:06 | 0.5 |
| Ram | 2020-03-18 22:11:29 | 0 |
| Arjun | 2020-03-18 22:42:29 | 31 |
| Arjun | 2020-03-18 23:42:29 | 60 |

this data shows the timestamp of all user visits in a website and the time difference between each consecutive visit in minutes.
I want to create a logic that creates session_id for each user, where if the difference between two timestamps is 30 minutes, we create a new session_id.

This is certainly possible through for loops. But if there are any faster methods, please let me know. I have more than 20 million data and if loops takes a lot of time!

Final result should be something like this:

| user | timestamp | minutes | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:53:06 | 0 | 1 |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:54:06 | 1 | 1 |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:56:36 | 2.5 | 1 |
| Ram | 2020-07-25 12:57:06 | 0.5 | 1 |
| Arjun | 2020-03-18 22:11:29 | 0 | 2 |
| Arjun | 2020-03-18 22:42:29 | 31 | 3 |
| Arjun | 2020-03-18 23:42:29 | 60 | 4 |

Answer (score 2):

Increment the session_id when:

1. The user changes, or
2. Minutes > 30

###### Code:

```
df["session_id"] = ((df["user"]!=df["user"].shift())|(df["minutes"]>30)).cumsum()
```

###### Output:

```
             user           timestamp  minutes  session_id
Ram    2020-07-25 2021-09-06 12:53:06      0.0           1
Ram    2020-07-25 2021-09-06 12:54:06      1.0           1
Ram    2020-07-25 2021-09-06 12:56:36      2.5           1
Ram    2020-07-25 2021-09-06 12:57:06      0.5           1
Ram    2020-03-18 2021-09-06 22:11:29      0.0           2
Arjun  2020-03-18 2021-09-06 22:42:29     31.0           3
Arjun  2020-03-18 2021-09-06 23:42:29     60.0           4
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tried this, but it's returning a column of null values. can you check once again?

Comment: @RahulMonish - This definitely works for me, at least on the example data you provided.